# How to use intuit webhook verifier token on a webhook

Tags: ruby-on-rails, intuit-partner-platform

I have created a webhook with intuit developer account
https://developer.intuit.com/app/developer/qbo/docs/develop/webhooks#configuring-webhooks

It works fine, my question is how to use the verifier token in order to secure the webhook?

I see various intuit headers but not sure how to use them

[image: headers]

Answer (score 0):

There is a detailed documentation

1. Hash the notification payload with HMAC_SHA256_ALGORITHM using your verifier token as the key.
2. Convert the intuit-signature header from base-64 to base-16.
3. Compare the value from step 1 to the intuit-signature header from the notification. The values should be identical.

https://developer.intuit.com/app/developer/qbo/docs/develop/webhooks/managing-webhooks-notifications#validating-the-notification

Here is some more information how to generate the HMAC hash ([Using HMAC SHA256 in Ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34855049/using-hmac-sha256-in-ruby)) and how to convert the base64 signature to base16 ([Converting a hexadecimal digest to base64 in Ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9986971/converting-a-hexadecimal-digest-to-base64-in-ruby)). To compare the values Rails does implement a `safe_compare` method (https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/SecurityUtils.html).